# Term for measuring in fractions of 1

Tags: measuring-units

When you measure in fractions of 100, you call it a *percentage*. When you measure in fractions of 1000, you call it *promille* or *per mil*. There are even words for fractions of 10000 or 100000.

But what do you call it when you measure in fractions of 1?

Comment: 1/1 = 1, 2/1 = 2, 3/1 = 3... Where I'm from that's called *counting*. (^_^)

Comment: As @RegD says, your 'fractions of 1' are just plain old numbers.  The body of this question doesn't fit the title.

Comment: @Jasper Loy You are right. I completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: The original title (What do you call the scale [0..1]?) was much much clearer. I do not want to start an edit war... but I would suggest reverting to the first revision. Clearly the OP refers to the fact that 10%=0.1, 35%=0.35 etc

Comment: @Jasper: it means (well, I interpret it as) *decimal numbers between 0 and 1*.

Comment: @nico: that was exactly what I meant, thank you. :)

Comment: Also, in case you're interested, fractions represented as one over some number (1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, etc.) are called "unit fractions".

Comment: It is called a "proper fraction": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29#Proper_and_improper_common_fractions.

Answer (score 10):

Answering here from the perspective of a physical scientist.

Such comparisons are often dimensionless (say change in length over initial length, which is length/length = 1), and when they are we often say *"fractional"*.

As in *"the strain is the fractional change in length"*, or *"here we compare the factional signal loss between..."*.

Comment: Aren't percentages dimensionless as well? Still, thanks for the alternative! :)

Comment: @Pepijn: Well, yes, but the are 1/100 (that is one per one hundred or *"pre cent"*), and as used by physicists "fraction" is taken to be normalized (to use [prash's good suggestion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37009/term-for-measuring-in-fractions-of-1/37030#37030)).

Answer (score 5):

If you rewrite a percentage in the interval [0;1] then you get a *proportion* or simply a *decimal number*.

This, always keeping in mind that, for instance
0.1 = 10% = 100‰ = 1000‱

Comment: I feel that decimal number strongly implies (as it does) that you can go below 0.0 and beyond 1.0. However, proportion seems a decent alternative.

Comment: @Pepijn: well, technically you can go beyond 1 (e.g. 200%=2) and below 0 (-50% = -0.5).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on context, you can even use the word [normalized](http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Similarity/Normalization.html). In fields that use statistical techniques, we use factors that change an arbitrary number into one that has the range [0,1]. Such factors are usually called [normalization factors](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/irbookonlinereading.pdf) or [normalizing constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizing_constant).

They speak about it on [the stats StackExchange site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/how-to-represent-an-unbounded-variable-as-number-between-0-and-1) -- read the comments and note the tag used.